# Adjust tableviewcell height based on contents

Tags: ios, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I'm creating a facebook like app. And I want to adjust the cell's height based on contents. The tableviewcell are consist of `UIImageView`, `UILabel` and `UIButton`. I can adjust the cell's height by using `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate, but, there's a time that there's no image in a certain cell.

As far as I know, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` was first called. So, I can't pass object height that was calculated in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

I want to know if I can pass object's height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, height of image preview in cell is fixed. And you can calculate height of cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

If you want to use dynamic image size, you should receive image height from API when you request objects for cell. In this case you can calculate height for cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` too.

Or you can download image first and retrieve height from UImage.

Usually, I use second or first case in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is:

Add `@property (strong, nonatomic) MyCell* prototypeCell;` to controller.

Create a getter:

```
- (MyCell*) prototypeCell {
  if (!_prototypeCell) {
    _prototypeCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
  }

 return _prototypeCell;
}
```

Move all code, related to cell configuration from `cellForRow` to Cell class (you can take a look here: [How to access properties in multiple custom tableviewcells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913851/how-to-access-properties-in-multiple-custom-tableviewcells/24913967#24913967))

**Modify heightForRow:**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  CGSize size = [self.prototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
  return size.height+1;   
}
```

Works with autolayout. If you don't have autolayout enabled - you can calculate manually.

To improve performance on iOs7 use:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 300; // or any number based on your estimation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called first. It is here you have to check if the cell at that particular indexPath has an image and set the height accordingly. You haven't provided any code. But assuming you have an array of objects with the image and strings required for populating the tableView, the code should look somewhat like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomObject *object = (CustomObject *)[arrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (object.cellImage != null) {
        return 60; //height for row that has image;
    }
    return 44; //those without image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, is the quick answer.

The slower answer is that the height (or estimated height) methods are called before any cells are loaded. Prior to iOS8 you need to do height calculations separately.

As of iOS8 the table will be able to use Autolayout to derive the cell height - see What's new in table and collection views from WWDC 2014.